# How to find which process deleted my file in Windows

Tags: windows, delete-file, process-monitor

In simplest terms, is there a simple way or program which can help identify who/which process has deleted the file.

Even in the latest version of Process Monitor by SysInternals, I couldn't find an event that directly tells that "This is a delete operation and performed by a certain PID or process name".

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### "Normal" deletes

In Process Monitor, a real delete operation can be identified by the "delete on close" option in the "Details" column. You can use that as a filter:

Detail, Contains, Delete On Close

[image: Process Monitor filter for deletions]

Why? Well, there is the [DeleteFile()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-deletefilea) Windows API, that says:

> The DeleteFile function marks a file for deletion on close.

Also, [CreateFile()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) has a flag `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`:

> The file is to be deleted immediately after all of its handles are closed, which includes the specified handle and any other open or duplicated handles.

Likely, DeleteFile() just calls CreateFile() with that parameter. That's why you don't see an operation called "DeleteFile", but rather unexpectedly that the file is deleted in an operation called "CreateFile".

### Recycle bin deletes

Why do I say "real delete operation"? Well, Windows Explorer does not delete files when you delete them, but moves them into the recycle bin. That's not a delete operation from OS point of view. It's a move operation.

For a recycle operation, add two filters:

1. Operation, Is, SetRenameInformationFile
2. Detail, Contains, $RECYCLE.BIN

[image: Process Monitor, find Recycle Bin operation]

### Low level deletes

Some programs operate on a lower level and use API like SetDispositionInformationFile() or SetDispositionInformationEx(). See the low level [ZwSetInformationFile()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-zwsetinformationfile) or [NtSetInformationFile()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntsetinformationfile) on MSDN. That method takes [a parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddk/ns-ntddk-_file_disposition_information_ex):

> FILE_DISPOSITION_DELETE   0x00000001  Specifies the system should delete a file.

In my case (using [FastCopy](https://fastcopy.jp/)), the following Process Monitor filter captured it:

1. Operation, equals, SetDispositionInformationEx
2. Detail, contains, FILE_DISPOSITION_DELETE

Comment: Hi @Thomas, Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I confirm that the parameters SetRenameInformationFile and $RECYCLE.BIN works perfectly when any third-party software moves the file to Recycle bin. However, the other parameter DELETE ON CLOSE is not detecting the real time delete by the third-party software that I am using for testing. I am using FreeFileSync software to completely delete the file. It's like pressing SHIFT+DEL. That operation does not show up in Process monitor if I just have the filter Detail contains DELETE ON CLOSE. 
Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Hi @Thomas, As a reference, please look at the below video link to know what I am talking about actually.
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/98eff720932d0c9093b8bc8717dd58a320230720164523/8815b1

Comment: @JawadAliQamar: thanks for the video, I see. I can imagine that there are programs (like e.g. FastCopy, possibly FreeFileSync as well) that operate on a very low level and thus don't get monitored. I'll have a look if I can figure something out on those.

Comment: @JawadAliQamar: I found out how FastCopy does it and added that to the answer

Comment: Hi @Thomas, that worked like a charm. Thank you so much for your valuable input.
Much Appreciated.